# Regex to replace 'NO-BREAK SPACE'

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am looking for a regex to replace 'NO-BREAK SPACE's from a string.

There are some question on SO related to 'NO-BREAK SPACE', but none seems to point me to the right answer.

So far, i tried to use (second character of the String "A B" is a no break space) without success:

```
"A B".replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(160),"g"),"xxx");
"A B".replace($('<b>&nbsp;</b>').text(), 'xxx');
"A B".replace(/\xA0/,'xxx');
"A B".replace(/\\xA0/,'xxx');
"A B".replace(/\u00A0/,'xxx');
"A B".replace(/\\u00A0/,'xxx');
```

**UPDATE:** Stupid me. Truth is i tested with the wrong character for quite some time.

Comment: If you want to replace all whitespace characters (new line included), you might want to use `\s`. If you want to replace horizontal whitespace only, you might want to use `[ \t\xA0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000]`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The actual character in your string is [NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE (U+202F)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm), not the usual `\xA0`.

Something like

```
.replace(/[\u202F\u00A0]/, "...")
```

should work for you.

Comment: stupid me. truth is i tested with the wrong character for quite some time. thanks for the hint

Comment: Your post is really help a lot! Thanks, Georg!

Answer (score 11):

Apart from space, NO-BREAK SPACE, etc. there are also other spaces characters that can also appear in strings.

Here is the complete Unicode list for spaces. Source: http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html

| Number | Character name |
| --- | --- |
| \u0020 | space |
| \u00A0 | no-break space |
| \u1680 | Ogham space mark |
| \u180E | Mongolian vowel separator |
| \u2000 | en quad |
| \u2001 | em quad |
| \u2002 | en space (nut) |
| \u2003 | em space (mutton) |
| \u2004 | three-per-em space (thick space) |
| \u2005 | four-per-em space (mid space) |
| \u2006 | six-per-em space |
| \u2007 | figure space |
| \u2008 | punctuation space |
| \u2009 | thin space |
| \u200A | hair space |
| \u200B | zero width space |
| \u202F | narrow no-break space |
| \u205F | medium mathematical space |
| \u3000 | ideographic space |
| \uFEFF | zero width no-break space |

Therefore, to replace all strange spaces

```
.replace(/[\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200B\u202F\u205F\u3000\uFEFF]/, " ")
```

From the above, you may exclude `\u1680`, since it's "usually not really a space but a dash".

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know about the facts that @georg explained in his answer.

But it works if you just copy the character between `A` and `B` and paste it inside the `.replace()` function.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/gpxuddqk/).

And the snippet.

```js
alert("A B".replace(' ', 'xxx'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no [unicode category](https://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx) that cover this use-case.

The regex in @Rakesh's answer was missing some characters from the list of unicode-space and I needed c#-flavor.

Here the list is converted to a c#-expression that produces regex-pattern:

```cs
string.Concat("{", string.Join("|", new[]
{
    new { c = '\u0020', desc = "space" },
    new { c = '\u00A0', desc = "no-break space" },
    new { c = '\u1680', desc = "Ogham space mark" },
    new { c = '\u180E', desc = "Mongolian vowel separator" },
    new { c = '\u2000', desc = "en quad" },
    new { c = '\u2001', desc = "em quad" },
    new { c = '\u2002', desc = "en space (nut)" },
    new { c = '\u2003', desc = "em space (mutton)" },
    new { c = '\u2004', desc = "three-per-em space (thick space)" },
    new { c = '\u2005', desc = "four-per-em space (mid space)" },
    new { c = '\u2006', desc = "six-per-em space" },
    new { c = '\u2007', desc = "figure space" },
    new { c = '\u2008', desc = "punctuation space" },
    new { c = '\u2009', desc = "thin space" },
    new { c = '\u200A', desc = "hair space" },
    new { c = '\u200B', desc = "zero width space" },
    new { c = '\u202F', desc = "narrow no-break space" },
    new { c = '\u205F', desc = "medium mathematical space" },
    new { c = '\u3000', desc = "ideographic space" },
    new { c = '\uFEFF', desc = "zero width no-break space" },
}
.Select(a => $"\\u{(int)a.c:X4}")
), "}")

// Become "{\u0020|\u00A0|\u1680|\u180E|\u2000|\u2001|\u2002|\u2003|\u2004|\u2005|\u2006|\u2007|\u2008|\u2009|\u200A|\u200B|\u202F|\u205F|\u3000|\uFEFF}"
```

<sub>For copy-paste and view in [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx):

`.Select(a => new { a.c, num = (int)a.c, part = $"\\u{(int)a.c:X4}", a.desc })`</sub>