# RStudio saving to .csv replaces space with '¬†' in string

Tags: r, csv, encoding

I'm saving a data frame to a .csv. One column is character format, I have replaced all spaces with '.' using `df$Col <- gsub(" ", ".", df$Col)`, but for one row this does not work and still displays the string with a space in RStudio.

After exporting with `write.csv` and opening in Excel, the space in the string has been replaced with '¬†'. I'm guessing it is something to do with the .csv encoding? Either when writing, or (more likely) when I've loaded the original .csv into RStudio. But there's nothing obvious I've done to make it happen. I've used multiple other files in the same workflow without this happening, and in the problem .csv it's only the rows with this one specific string where it is happening. How can I correct this in R? (I know I could use find and replace in Excel, but I'd rather know how to avoid this problem in the first place).

**Edit**

As requested in the comments, here is the output of `dput(charToRaw(x))`:

`as.raw(c(0x49, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x65, 0x72, 0x75, 0x73,  0xc2, 0xa0, 0x73, 0x70))`

**Edit 2**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6.8

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] boot_1.3-28      MCMCvis_0.15.5   ggplot2_3.4.0   
[4] stringr_1.4.0    tidyr_1.1.4      lubridate_1.7.10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3     pillar_1.7.0     compiler_4.1.1  
 [4] cellranger_1.1.0 tools_4.1.1      lifecycle_1.0.3 
 [7] tibble_3.1.7     gtable_0.3.0     lattice_0.20-44 
[10] pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_1.0.6      cli_3.4.1       
[13] DBI_1.1.1        jagsUI_1.5.2     rstudioapi_0.13 
[16] parallel_4.1.1   coda_0.19-4      withr_2.5.0     
[19] dplyr_1.0.9      rjags_4-13       generics_0.1.2  
[22] vctrs_0.5.1      grid_4.1.1       tidyselect_1.1.2
[25] glue_1.6.2       R6_2.5.1         fansi_1.0.3     
[28] readxl_1.4.0     purrr_0.3.4      magrittr_2.0.3  
[31] scales_1.2.0     ellipsis_0.3.2   assertthat_0.2.1
[34] colorspace_2.0-3 utf8_1.2.2       stringi_1.7.6   
[37] munsell_0.5.0    crayon_1.5.1
```

Comment: Is it definitely the same white-space `space` character as the other rows in `df`?

If it isn't then `gsub` won't be replacing it properly. If it is definitely the same `space` character, then I'm not sure.

Comment: @JudgedGem as far as I can tell it's the same. But I think that's the issue, it's displayed as a space by RStudio, but there's something wrong with the encoding when I load the original .csv

Comment: Can you isolate where it is happening, subset a single case, and copy and paste it into your question using `dput(charToRaw(x))`.  Looking at the bytes will tell us which problematic whitespace character we're dealing with.  You could also try `gsub("\\h", ".", df$Col, perl = TRUE)` to replace all horizontal whitespace.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento - `gsub("\\h", ".", df$Col, perl = TRUE)` has fixed it, thanks! Would be good to know why this is appearing though. I've added the `dput(charToRaw(x))` details to the question...

Comment: `0xc2, 0xa0`  is `Â` (U+00C2,  *Latin Capital Letter A With Circumflex*)  and ` ` (U+00A0,  *No-Break Space*) - the same as ˙UTF8˙ representation of  ` ` (U+00A0,  *No-Break Space*) .  You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*):  `'\xa0'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'mac_roman')` returns `'¬†'`.  Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share (sanitized if necessary) `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: @JosefZ - thanks, session info added. I can't create a proper MRE without sharing the original .csv, but I'm not at liberty to share the data unfortunately. Is it possible to fix without that?

Comment: `gsub("[\u00A0\u0020]", ".", x)` or `gsub("\u00A0|\u0020", ".", x)`  or `gsub("\u00A0|\\s", ".", x)` should work. Strangely enough, `\\s` does not match U+00A0, *No-Break Space* in R ([unlike Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51399843/3439404)). I'm running `R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`…