# Replacing " " space with "" nothing using gsub( " ", "", chr)

Tags: r, encoding, gsub, read.csv

Here is the format of my data, imported from a CSV.

```
print(donnees_ventes3$V8[1:10])
 [1] "0,00000"     "0,00000"     "0,00000"     "0,00000"     "0,00000"     "0,00000"     "4,22476"     "0,00000"     "1 086,16998" "0,00000"
```

I'm changing the "," for "." successfully but when getting to remove the space between the thousand and the hundred, it's not working.

Here is what I tried:

```
gsub(" ", "", donnees_ventes3$V8)
gsub(" ", "\\", donnees_ventes3$V8)
gsub("\\ ", "\\", donnees_ventes3$V8)
gsub("\\ ", "", donnees_ventes3$V8)
gsub("\\  ", "\\", donnees_ventes3$V8)` #thought there might be two space.
```

Also tried:

```
str_replace_all(donnees_ventes3$V8,” “, “”)
```

I can't give a reproducible example as I tried creating an example vector:

```
exemple <- c("0,00000", "0,00000", "0,00000", "0,00000", "0,00000", "0,00000", "4,22476", "0,00000", "1 086,16998", "0,00000")
```

for which the `gsub(" ", "", exemple)` works and changes the 9th data for "1086,16998"

It means it has something to do with importing the csv and the format of the " " blank space.
Here is how I import it:

```
read.csv("csv path", encoding="UTF-8", header=FALSE)
```

Might it might be the encoding?

Anyone has a clue about whats wrong here?

Comment: Can you elaborate ? because 9th position in my vector is : 1 086,16998.

Using gsub to change "," to "." and then changing my chr to num works for numbers under a thousand. Over that, the value becomes NA.

Comment: if it's a weird encoding thing, stringr::str_squish() might standardize the internal whitespace and then let you process it? compete shot in the dark without seeing your data though

Comment: Try `gsub("\\s", "", exemple)`. It might be a thin space character.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's unfortunatly not working. Tried the str_trim() to and trimws() which didn't work.

Comment: Tried gsub("\\s", "", donnees_ventes3$V8), didn't work either. 

Tried replacing "\\s" with 0x20 and 0xE2 which are suppose to be the utf-8 encoding of spance and thin space character

Answer (score 5):

### All that is spacy is not whitespace

Base R functions like `gsub()` use POSIX Extended Regular Expressions (when `perl=FALSE`). In these `\s` is [defined](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) as the character set `[ \t\r\n\v\f]`, i.e. space, tab, carriage return, new line, vertical tab, form feed.

However, Unicode text can contain characters that print like a space but are not included in this set, such as [No-Break Space](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A0) (NBSP), i.e. `\U00A0`.

```r
space  <- "This is a space"
not_space  <- "This\U00A0is\U00A0not"
print(space) # [1] "This is a space"
print(not_space) # [1] "This is not"
```

You cannot use `"\\s"` to replace these characters:

```r
gsub("\\s", "", not_space)
# [1] "This is not"
```

### Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE)

You can capture these spacy characters with PCRE. Interestingly, the Perl regex [docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Whitespace) indicate that `\s` includes NBSP but R seems not yet to have implemented this:

```
gsub("\\s", "", not_space, perl= TRUE)
# [1] "This is not"
```

However, the PCRE docs note:

> The sequences \h, \H, \v, and \V are features that were added to Perl at release 5.10

These represent horizontal and vertical spaces, and their negation. `\h` captures the 19 Unicode horizontal space characters, including `NBSP`:

```r
gsub("\\h", "", space, perl= TRUE)
# [1] "Thisisaspace"
gsub("\\h", "", not_space, perl= TRUE)
# [1] "Thisisnot"
```

### Identifying other characters

In the event you have a character not captured by `\h` or `\v`, you can easily see what it is with `stringr::str_view()`:

```r
stringr::str_view(space) 
# [1] │ This is a space
stringr::str_view(not_space) 
# [1] │ This{\u00a0}is{\u00a0}not
```

Or if you prefer only base R you can identify them slightly less clearly:

```r
# Unicode for space (0020)
as.hexmode(utf8ToInt(" ")) # 20
# Unicode for NBSP, the 5th character of not_space
as.hexmode(utf8ToInt(substr(not_space, 5,5))) # a0
```

### Individual replacements

It is laborious but you can replace individual characters by their character code:

```r
gsub("\U00A0", "", not_space)
# [1] "Thisisnot"
```

### Replacing all non-digits

Depending on your ultimate goal, you might want to remove all characters that are not digits:

```r
v  <- c("1\U{00A0}086,16998", "1\U{00A0}086,16998")
print(v) # [1] "1 086,16998"
gsub("\\D+", "", v)
# [1] "108616998" "108616998"
```

Or if you are trying to remove spaces and change commas to decimal points you could remove all characters that are not digits and commas, then substitute the commas:

```r
v |>
    gsub("[^0-9,]", "", x=_) |>
    gsub(",", ".", x=_)
# [1] "1086.16998" "1086.16998"
```

### Replacing all Unicode space characters

Based on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790440/regex-to-replace-no-break-space) linked by Roland, `"\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200B\u202F\u205F\u3000\uFEFF"` seems to be a comprehensive list of the 19 Unicode characters for spaces.

These are the same 19 horizontal space characters covered in the [PCRE specification](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html), so should be covered by `\h` with `perl = TRUE`. However, if you can't use PCRE, or you want to add in extra characters, you can list the relevant character codes and replace them with a space using [`chartr()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chartr.html):

```r
v <- chartr(
    "\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200B\u202F\u205F\u3000\uFEFF",
    paste(rep(" ", 19), collapse = ""),
    v
)
```

Then apply whatever code you had written for data which contains spaces.

Comment: Or based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790440/regex-to-replace-no-break-space): `gsub("\u00A0\u00A1|\u1680|\u180E|\u2000|\u2001|\u2002|\u2003|\u2004|\u2005|\u2006|\u2007|\u2008|\u2009|\u200A|\u200B|\u202F|\u205F|\u3000|\uFEFF", "", x)`

Comment: @Roland thanks that's a useful list - have updated